# System.Drawing.Icon doesn't exist

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create an icon from a stream like this for example:

```
System.IO.Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourReferencedAssembly;component/YourPossibleSubFolder/YourResourceFile.ico")).Stream;
```

Then when I try to assign it like this it has no notion of Icon inside
Drawing, I tried adding the reference and still nothing:

```
tbi.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
```

Having this at the top:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Here's the error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Icon' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Its really puzzling to me, I'd appreciate any ideas on what simple thing I
must have forgot to add.

Comment: A Visual Studio project targeting WPF doesn't by default reference the System.Drawing assembly. This is because elements from the System.Drawing namespaces (like Icon) are typically not used in WPF applications. Why are you using System.Drawing.Icon in a WPF application?

Comment: I am using this nuget for notification bar icon:
www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx and in the example he gives to load an icon he uses the System.Drawing namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that your project isn't referencing that assembly.

To fix it:

1. Go to your project references
2. Right click and select "Add Reference..."
3. Under Assemblies, select "System.Drawing"

I'm hoping that should take care of it

Comment: That did it. Its weird that having 'Using System.Drawing;' didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: A project has to reference the assembly before a class can. Most of the basic C# projects (WPF Windows, Console Applications etc) already reference a bunch of assemblies by default, but System.Drawing just doesn't happen to be one of those